# how to do data-bind for complex model knockout

Tags: javascript, algorithm, knockout.js

I am a newbee to knockout, I'm trying to move from the MVC ViewModel binding.

I have a complex model:

SearchStudentsModel which has 2 properties

1. Collection of Students (Subset of students)
2. Number of Students overall

Note that the length of the collection isn't equal to the number overall.

I need to implement a search functionality
Student will have all the regular properties plus IsActive indicator.
I use ul and li tags to data-bind the details.

The search screen should facilitate the user in marking the active flag with an indicator (on and off) and immediately data should be saved in the database.

All the examples I referred to talk about only one level of model.  I have a SearchStudent model and within that I have a collection of students.

How should the binding be for this hierarchy of models?

Comment: The question is a bit broad since it is essentially, "can you design the knockout for my website?" You mention that you can't find an example that matches your exact requirements, but do you need an example to get started? knockout.js is pretty intuitive and you should be able to get something started before you get stuck. Even if you get the knockout view models wrong the first time, there's nothing preventing you from rewriting it after you've made your mistakes. A starting point is that your `SearchStudent` model and `Student` models can both be observables.

Comment: A little bit more code or a **jsfiddle** will be better. what have you done until now to design you site/viewmodel/binding?

Comment: @roliu - My mistake, I should have pasted the code i worked out.
http://jsfiddle.net/babludutt/rQ2jH/

Comment: @Martin - Please refer this. Just to give you an idea of what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **refactored** your jsFiddle. Hoping you can now understand knockoutJS better. It is not your whole page/Knockout, but I think with this **snippet** your problem can be **solved**.

**the markup:**

```
<button id="searchEmployees" type="button" data-bind="click: search">Search</button>

<li data-bind="foreach: Employees">
ID: <span data-bind="text: Id"></span><br/>
Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span><br/>
Active: <span data-bind="click: ToggleActivation, text: IsActive"></span> &lt;-- click<br/>
</li>

<span data-bind="text: Employees().length"></span> of
<span data-bind="text: AllEmployees().length"></span>
```

**the js/viewmodel**

```
function Employee(id, name, isactive){

    var self = this;

    self.IsActive = ko.observable(isactive);
    self.Id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);

    self.ToggleActivation = function () {
    if(self.IsActive() === true)
        self.IsActive(false);
    else
        self.IsActive(true);
    };
}

var searchEmployeeViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;

    self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AllEmployees = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.search = function () {
        //Ajax call to populate Employees - foreach on onsuccess

        var employee1 = new Employee(2, "Jane Doe", true);
        var employee2 = new Employee(3, "Kyle Doe", false);
        var employee3 = new Employee(4, "Tyra Doe", false);

        var employee = new Employee(1, "John Doe", true);

        self.AllEmployees.push(employee);
        self.AllEmployees.push(employee1);
        self.AllEmployees.push(employee2);
        self.AllEmployees.push(employee3);

        self.Employees.push(employee);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new searchEmployeeViewModel());
});
```

or you can **simply use** [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQ2jH/2/) if you do not like reading my code here ;)